PCB trace impedance infinite equivalent impedance of RLC model
I am trying to understand the PCB trace impedance model. Although not exactly, if we take a very small section of a PCB trace as an example, let's assume that it is in the form of series R, series L and parallel C. If we look at the impedance of this, we can see that it is 119 Ω. However, if we connect the same circuit one after the other, shouldn't the impedance decrease? For example, in the first equivalent circuit model, it can be seen that the impedance at 1 GHz is 119 Ω.
However, Wouldn't we expect it to impedance decrease when we connect infinite numbers of them one after the other? What am I missing?

Source PCB pcb trace equivalent circuit 





In my last simulation, we can see that the trace in the regional minor places where the accordions are located is 117 ohms, and the impedance of the major (mostly) flat traces is 119 ohms. In this case, shouldn't we consider these in parallel?

"Characteristic Impedance" do not change when you add one or more cells ... You just change the attenuation.


However, if we connect the same circuit one after the other, shouldn't
the impedance decrease?

The impedance of a section of transmission line is calculated assuming it is loaded with another identical section of transmission line which, in turn is loaded by another. At the end, it is assumed to be loaded by a simple resistor having a value that is equal to the characteristic impedance.
Or, you can assume it goes on to infinity (simplified t-line): -

Image from here.
The mathematical proof is like this where we solve for \$Z_{IN}\$ on the left: -
$$$$
$$Z_{IN}\hspace{0.5cm} =\hspace{0.5cm} sL + \dfrac{1}{sC}||Z_{IN}\hspace{0.5cm} =\hspace{0.5cm} sL + \dfrac{Z_{IN}}{1 +sC Z_{IN}} $$
$$Z_{IN}\cdot (1 + sCZ_{IN})\hspace{0.5cm} =\hspace{0.5cm}sL + s^2LCZ_{IN} + Z_{IN}$$
$$sCZ_{IN}^2\hspace{0.5cm} =\hspace{0.5cm} sL + s^2LCZ_{IN}
$$
$$Z_{IN}^2 \hspace{0.5cm}=\hspace{0.5cm}\dfrac{L}{C} + sL Z_{IN}$$
That looks about as far as it goes but, if we imagine our section of t-line shrunk towards zero length, \$sL\cdot Z_{IN}\$ becomes insignificant compared to \$\frac{L}{C}\$ hence: -
$$Z_{IN} = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$
T-line images stolen from one of my earlier answers.
